# Kafka Streams Monitoring

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is it any solution to monitor Kafka Streams topology? How can we determine state store or global state store is down or when applications has a problem with topology?

Answer (score 0):

You'd query for it

> `public KafkaStreams.State state()`
> Return the current [`KafkaStreams.State`](https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.State.html) of this `KafkaStreams` instance.

But ideally, you'd combine this information with logs and JMX metrics for a holistic view of the application. Same answer applies to any long running Java application.

Comment: Are there information about global state store?

Comment: What do you mean? The state of the global store would defer to the state of the individual application instances.

Comment: But what if global store while reading has been crash? Then whole topology is crashed ?

Comment: There could be a thundering herd crash of all instances of the application, sure. But you can set a exception handler in the Streams application, and gracefully terminate just the topology rather than the whole JVM. In which case, the mentioned `state()` method will return `NOT_RUNNING` and trying to query a global ktable will return an error indicating its in a non-healthy state